# VBA - Run Time Error 1004 'Application Defined or Object Defined Error'

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I have an Excel document that copies a template sheet into a new sheet on the first time it runs. Any more sheets that follow this template are appended to the newly created sheet.

I'm getting the error in the title in this section of code:

```
If Worksheets("User Configuration").Cells(9, 15).Value = 1 Then
  Worksheets("Cable Cards Template").Range("A1:J33").Copy

  With Worksheets("Cable Cards")
  **.Range(Cells(RangeStartRow, RangeStartColumn), Cells(RangeEndRow, RangeEndColumn)).PasteSpecial xlValues**
    .Range(Cells(RangeStartRow, RangeStartColumn), Cells(RangeEndRow, RangeEndColumn)).PasteSpecial xlFormats
  End With

  Worksheets("Cable Cards Template").Shapes("Picture 1").Copy
  Worksheets("Cable Cards").Paste Cells(RangeStartRow, RangeStartColumn)

  Call Sheets.FormatCableCardRows      
End If
```

Basically if the `If` statement is true (the cell = 1), then a range on a particular sheet should be copied and pasted into the new sheet at the range given using `PasteSpecial` for values and formatting. Following that, the "newly created" sheet should have an image copied into the top left cell of the template and then a subroutine is called to format the rows of the new sheet.

I'm getting the error at the first `.Range` call after the `With Worksheets("Cable Cards")` statement. I've tried not using the `With` statement, copying values directly instead of paste-special etc. The weird thing is that this will run on the first go, when the new sheet is created via:

```
If (RangeStartRow = 1) Then
  Worksheets.Add().Name = "Cable Cards" ' Create new sheet with given name only on first cable card
  Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 9.43
  Columns(6).ColumnWidth = 11
  Columns(10).ColumnWidth = 9
  Call FormatForA5Printing("Cable Cards", 71)
End If
```

but on the 2nd go, it fails entirely, with the `Run Time Error 1004 'Application Defined or Object Defined Error'`. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 15):

Your cells object is not fully qualified. You need to add a `DOT` before the cells object. For example

```
With Worksheets("Cable Cards")
    .Range(.Cells(RangeStartRow, RangeStartColumn), _
           .Cells(RangeEndRow, RangeEndColumn)).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Similarly, fully qualify all your Cells object.

Comment: That was it, thank you for that, would've never spotted it otherwise!

Comment: +1 It is remarkable how often one finds errors stemming from not qualifying ranges appropriately.

Answer (score 6):

*Solution #1*:
Your statement

```
.Range(Cells(RangeStartRow, RangeStartColumn), Cells(RangeEndRow, RangeEndColumn)).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

does not refer to a proper `Range` to act upon. Instead,

```
.Range(.Cells(RangeStartRow, RangeStartColumn), .Cells(RangeEndRow, RangeEndColumn)).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

does (and similarly in some other cases).

*Solution #2*:
Activate `Worksheets("Cable Cards")` prior to using its cells.

**Explanation**:
`Cells(RangeStartRow, RangeStartColumn)` (e.g.) gives you a `Range`, that *would* be ok, and that is why you often see `Cells` used in this way. But since it is not applied to a specific object, it applies to the `ActiveSheet`. Thus, your code attempts using `.Range(rng1, rng2)`, where `.Range` is a method of one `Worksheet` object and `rng1` and `rng2` are in a different `Worksheet`.

There are two checks that you can do to make this quite evident:

1. Activate your `Worksheets("Cable Cards")` prior to executing your `Sub` and it will start working (now you have well-formed references to `Range`s). For the code you posted, adding `.Activate` right after `With...` would indeed be a solution, although you might have a similar problem somewhere else in your code when referring to a `Range` in another `Worksheet`.
2. With a sheet other than `Worksheets("Cable Cards")` active, set a breakpoint at the line throwing the error, start your `Sub`, and when execution breaks, write at the immediate window

   `Debug.Print Cells(RangeStartRow, RangeStartColumn).Address(external:=True)`

   `Debug.Print .Cells(RangeStartRow, RangeStartColumn).Address(external:=True)`

   and see the different outcomes.

**Conclusion**:
Using `Cells` or `Range` without a specified object (e.g., `Worksheet`, or `Range`) might be dangerous, especially when working with more than one `Sheet`, unless one is quite sure about what `Sheet` is active.

Answer (score 1):

Assgining a value that starts with a "=" will kick in formula evaluation and gave in my case the above mentioned error #1004. Prepending it with a space was the ticket for me.