# VBA vlookup reference in different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel 2007, I am looping through the values of column 4 in Sheet 2. Still in Sheet 2, I want to output the result of my vlookup formula into column 5. The vlookup formula needs to refer to Sheet 1 where the reference columns are. In order to do so I have the following formula

```
Range("E2") = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("D2"), _
          Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C65536"), 1, False)
```

Problem, it returns error code 1004. I read that it was because I needed to Select Sheet 1 before running the formulas such as:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
```

But then the searched value Range ("D2") doesn't belong to Sheet 1 and it still return code 1004 after having brought Sheet 1 into view.

What is the correct way to refer to a different sheet in this case?

Comment: Why are you using VBA to return the result of a formula that could be entered directly in `Worksheets("Sheet2").range("E2")`?

Comment: I agree with Mark's logic so i posted an alternative to your code which will do exactly the same. But, if you want to stick to your logic then try to add `.Value` to your array argument. Like this `Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Range("D2"),Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C65536").Value, 1, False)`. Also, are you returning the values in `Column A`? You use `1` in the `Vlookup` 3rd argument which is the `col_index_num`.

Comment: @Mark: This code is contained in a loop, iterating for several columns, outputting the result into string variables that I will concatenate at the end of the processing of each row into the last column. I have only simplified my code to avoid pasting my entire macro here.

Comment: @L42: As I mentioned it to Mark, I am outputting the results into a variable; Range("E2") is actually MyStringVar1, as I have several of these variable/formulas to put into place. I have tried using     .value but it made the loop much slower and still returned 1004.

Comment: yep, i added something that sticks with your logic. Also, as i've commented on the code, if what your searching is not found, `Vlookup` will fail and will return `Runtime Error 1004`. So you have to handle it using `Error Handlers` also shown in the code. And yes, no need to add `.Value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been many functions, macros and objects since I posted this question. The way I handled it, which is mentioned in one of the answers here, is by creating a string function that handles the errors that get generate by the vlookup function, and returns either nothing or the vlookup result if any.

```
Function fsVlookup(ByVal pSearch As Range, ByVal pMatrix As Range, ByVal pMatColNum As Integer) As String
    Dim s As String
    On Error Resume Next
    s = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(pSearch, pMatrix, pMatColNum, False)
    If IsError(s) Then
        fsVlookup = ""
    Else
        fsVlookup = s
    End If
End Function
```

One could argue about the position of the error handling or by shortening this code, but it works in all cases for me, and as they say, "if it ain't broke, don't try and fix it".

Comment: This always returns, in case of an error, the value of the previous success lookup.  Atleast for me..

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

With ws
    .Range("E2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D2,Sheet1!$A:$C,1,0)"
End With

End Sub
```

This just the simplified version of what you want.
No need to use `Application` if you will just output the answer in the `Range("E2")`.

If you want to stick with your logic, declare the variables.
See below for example.

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim MyStringVar1 As String

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set rng = ws2.Range("D2")

With ws2
    On Error Resume Next 'add this because if value is not found, vlookup fails, you get 1004
    MyStringVar1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng, ws1.Range("A1:C65536").Value, 1, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If MyStringVar1 = "" Then MsgBox "Item not found" Else MsgBox MyStringVar1
End With

End Sub
```

Hope this get's you started.

Comment: I have only just realised that the reference value I am searching for within the matrix must be in the first column, at least when creating a simple formula. I have therefore concatenated all the values I need that are based on my initial requirements and it works fine. But I will test your Test macro as I am interested in running this logic in the background rather than having a cell formula.

Comment: +1 for defining which worksheet rng belongs on. If you declare your variables and define them properly, you shouldn't have to select sheets.

Answer (score 3):

The answer your question: *the correct way to refer to a different sheet is by appropriately qualifying each `Range` you use*.
Please read [this **explanation**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20605401/2707864) and its **conclusion**, which I guess will give essential information.

The error you are getting is likely due to the sought-for value `Sheet2!D2` not being found in the searched range `Sheet1!A1:A65536`. This may stem from two cases:

1. The value is actually not present (pointed out by chris nielsen).
2. You are searching the wrong Range. If the `ActiveSheet` is `Sheet1`, then using `Range("D2")` without qualifying it will be searching for `Sheet1!D2`, and it will throw the same error even if the sought-for value is present in the correct Range.
   Code accounting for this (and items below) follows:

   ```
   Sub srch()
       Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
       Dim srchres As Variant

       Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
       Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

       On Error Resume Next
       srchres = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws2.Range("D2"), ws1.Range("A1:C65536"), 1, False)
       On Error GoTo 0
       If (IsEmpty(srchres)) Then
         ws2.Range("E2").Formula = CVErr(xlErrNA) ' Use whatever you want
       Else
         ws2.Range("E2").Value = srchres
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

I will point out a few additional notable points:

1. Catching the error as done by chris nielsen is a good practice, probably mandatory if using `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` (although it will not suitably handle case 2 above).
2. This catching is actually performed by the function `VLOOKUP` as entered in a cell (and, if the sought-for value is not found, the result of the error is presented as `#N/A` in the result). That is why the first soluton by L42 does not need any extra error handling (it is taken care by `=VLOOKUP...`).
3. Using `=VLOOKUP...` is fundamentally different from `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`: the first leaves a formula, whose result may change if the cells referenced change; the second writes a fixed value.
4. Both solutions by L42 qualify Ranges suitably.
5. You are searching the first column of the range, and returning the value in that same column. Other functions are available for that (although yours works fine).

Answer (score 2):

Your code work fine, provided the value in `Sheet2!D2` exists in `Sheet1!A:A`.  If it does not then error 1004 is raised.

To handle this case, try

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim MyStringVar1 As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    MyStringVar1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("D2"), _
      Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:C"), 1, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If IsEmpty(MyStringVar1) Then
        MsgBox "Value not found!"
    End If

    Range("E2") = MyStringVar1

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for using `IsEmpty` to check on `MyStringVar1`. I think it is a lot safer. :)