# Vlookup range not set properly

Tags: vba, excel

The code below is taken from [VBA vlookup reference in different sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739717/vba-vlookup-reference-in-different-sheet][1]), but having small changes as I tried to adjusted to my own needs. Short, the vlookup code needs to looks in **Sheet 1** - **column A** - starting from cell **A4** until the last entry row, verifies if the existing data is in **Sheet 2** - **column G** and if yes, take the value next to it from **column I**, go to **Sheet 1** and paste that in **column B** right next to its specific value. However, my approach doesn't work. Any help will be must appreciated!

```
        Sub vlookupB()
            Dim vlookup As Variant
            Dim lastrow As Long
            Dim ws As Worksheet

        ' i tried to set this in order to take into consideration the last entry from column A.
            Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
            lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 

            On Error Resume Next

            vlookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(ws.Range("A4" & lastrow), _  'start from A4 until its last entry from the column
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G7:I"), 3, False)

            On Error GoTo 0
            If IsEmpty(vlookup) Then

                ' do nothing    
            End If

            Range("B4:B") = vlookup 

        ' paste in column B from sheet1 starting from row B4 until the last entry I have in column A.

        ' so if for e.g. column A has entries until A200, then it should paste the value until B200 - of course, if the value is found in sheet2

    End Sub
```

Comment: `ws.Range("A4:A" & lastrow)`?

Comment: tried that as well. No result..

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G7:I")` ? you need to have a row number for column `I` as well. Also `If IsEmpty(vlookup) Then` needs to be replaced with `If IsError(vlookup) Then`

Comment: Thanks. Now works after i defined the range also for `Range("B4:B30000") = vlookup`  but it has the following problem. If in **Sheet1** column A - i have entries only until A200, the vlookup will paste the data until B200, but B201 to B3000 will equal = #N/A because there are no values from A201. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: `Range("B4:B" & lastrow)`?

Comment: My bad, works now. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the formulas into the cells then revert the formula results to their value.

```
Sub vlookupB()
    Dim vlookup As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastRow2 As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    lastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    With ws.Range("B4:B" & lastRow)
        .Formula = "=iferror(vlookup(A4, " & ws2.Range("G7:I" & lastRow2).Address(1, 1, external:=True) & ", 3, false), text(,))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```