# Copying a variable based range of cells to another Range

Tags: vba, excel

Hello from my code it should be evident what I am trying to do at this point. I am attempting to copy a range of cells from a static portion of a worksheet to a created column but I keep running into an error on a certain part of the formula I'm hoping that someone here has either a solution to the error, or a better method of taking one range of cells that can be static and bringing to a hard a reference point

```
Sub Mapping()

Dim Map As Worksheet
Dim Ath As Worksheet
Dim lastmap As Long
Dim lastath As Long
Set Ath = Sheets("Athena Greek God")
Set Map = Sheets("Mapping")
lastmap = Map.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
lastath = Ath.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row



Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Range("A1") = "EDITED"
Range("B1") = "EDITED 2"
Range("C1") = "EDITED 3"
Range("D1") = "EDITED 4"
Columns("A:D").AutoFit
Range("A1:D" & lastath).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

Clastath = Ath.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For x = Clastath To 1 Step -1
If ath.Cells(1, x) = "The Principals Book" Then
    ath.Range("D2: D" & lastath) = ath.Range(ath.Cells(2, x), ath.Cells(lastath, x))
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Error occurs here:

```
ath.Range("D2: D" & lastath) = ath.Range(ath.Cells(2, x), ath.Cells(lastath, x))
```

Comment: i am not getting any errors but try adding `Option Explicit` on top of your code and `Dim x As Integer`

Comment: You seem to have two worksheets you're working with, but you don't qualify any of your calls to `Range()` or `Cells()`, so it's difficult to tell what's expected from the code...  Without any qualifying worksheet reference (e.g. `Ath.Range(...)` or `Ath.Cells(...)`) you're referring to whatever happens to be the Active sheet, which makes for unreliable code.

Comment: Yes I've been rewriting that part numerous times so I didn't add the sheet reference just attempting to get it to work. Originally there is one in there, and will be one in there at the end

Comment: Edited with specific ranges

Comment: Run it and let it crash, hit debug and bring up the immediate window (ctrl-G) paste this and press enter: debug.print ath.Range("D2: D" & lastath).address then paste this and press enter debug.print ath.Range(ath.Cells(2, x), ath.Cells(lastath, x)).address then post the results here for me. If it spits an error tell me which line spits the error, probably the last one

Comment: Also, a little bit of sample data would make it a LOT easier to fix this for you.

Comment: At the moment when the error occures, check what value is in variable ```lastath```, what value is in ```x``` and what is the value you try to copy to the range ```"D2:D & lastath"``` and you should find the reason of the error. Note: When ```Range``` or ```Columns``` is used without an object qualifier, then it is a shortcut for ```ActiveSheet.Range/Columns```.

Comment: @DanDonoghue : Data sample would be useless here, the fix is just `Range.Value = Range.Value`. See my answer below

Comment: A complete statement of the problem (useful for people wanting to help) includes specification of the error you get.

Comment: @R3uK ```Range("A1").Value = Range("B1").Value``` is equivalent with ```Range("A1") = Range("B1")``` because ```Value``` is the default property of ```Range```. IMO data sample would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **use `.Value` or `.Value2` to transfer data between to ranges** like this :

```
Ath.Range("D2: D" & LastAth).Value2 = Ath.Range(Ath.Cells(2, x), Ath.Cells(LastAth, x)).Value2
```

The **main difference between these two** is :

1. `.Value2` gives you the underlying value of the cell (unformatted data)
2. `.Value` gives you the formatted value of the cell

For more details, take a look at [Charles William's blog here.](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/)

---

**As you seem to be working on two sheets** (not on the "mapping" one in the code you gave, if I got that right. If not just change `Ath.` to `Map.` where it need to be), **don't forget to use the references** you created (I added them everywhere, even before `Rows.Count` and `Columns.Count` to avoid errors if you open an old document on a new Excel version)

I got rid of the `Select`s and shorten code where I could, but I let the "Mapping" sheet as I guessed you'll use it later in your code.

Also don't forget to free your abject variables like this, when you won't use it afterwards :

```
Set Ath = Nothing
Set Map = Nothing
```

---

---

Here is **your code corrected, cleaned and tested** :

```
Sub Mapping()

Dim Map As Worksheet, _
    Ath As Worksheet, _
    LastAth As Long, _
    LastMap As Long, _
    CLastAth As Long, _
    x As Integer


Set Ath = Sheets("Athena Greek God")
Set Map = Sheets("Mapping")
LastMap = Map.Cells(Map.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
LastAth = Ath.Cells(Ath.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Ath.Columns("A:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Ath.Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("EDITED", "EDITED 2", "EDITED 3", "EDITED 4")
Ath.Columns("A:D").AutoFit

With Ath.Range("A1:D" & LastAth).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With


CLastAth = Ath.Cells(1, Ath.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For x = CLastAth To 1 Step -1
    If Ath.Cells(1, x) <> "The Principals Book" Then
    Else
        Ath.Range("D2: D" & LastAth).Value = Ath.Range(Ath.Cells(2, x), Ath.Cells(LastAth, x)).Value
    End If
Next x

Set Ath = Nothing
Set Map = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Take out the space after the :

I have also chopped your code down, Dimmed X and removed the selects for you:

```
Sub Mapping()

Dim Map As Worksheet, Ath As Worksheet, lastmap As Long, lastath As Long, X As Long, Clastath As Long
Set Ath = Sheets("Athena Greek God")
Set Map = Sheets("Mapping")
lastmap = Map.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
lastath = Ath.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Columns("A:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A1:D1") = Array("EDITED", "EDITED 2", "EDITED 3", "EDITED 4")
Columns("A:D").AutoFit
With Range("A1:D" & lastath).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

Clastath = Ath.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For X = Clastath To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(1, X) = "The Principals Book" Then
        Range("D2:D" & lastath) = Range(Cells(2, X), Cells(lastath, X))
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Edit: Also dimmed Clastath as long

Comment: Your code worked identical to mine, though much more efficient. I am still drawing an error in the same spot.. `Range("D2:D" & lastath) = Range(Cells(2, X), Cells(lastath, X))`

Comment: Do you have errors in the cells you are trying to copy? (Like `#N/A` or formulas that have returned errors?). If so, these need to be handled appropriately (either ignore the errors using `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Return 0` wrappers or check each cell for `IsError`.

Comment: @dom176 - `Range` and `Cells` have no defined parent worksheet.

Comment: @Jeeped yes that is correct, but let me to be a little bit more precise: when ```Range``` or ```Columns``` is used without an object qualifier, then it is a shortcut for ```ActiveSheet.Range/Columns```. So range and cells alway have 'parent' worksheet because thay can't exist as such 'in air'. But when this properties are used without such 'parent' qualifier, then they are considered to belong to the sheet which is active at that moment. Active sheet is the 'parent' sheet in such case.

Comment: @dee - Yes, all that's true. EXCEPT good practise dictates that we never *infer* a parent but rather we explicitly define a parent to everything we use as references. While I may be guilty of overusing the [With...End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) at times, it has not been used once in the above code snippet. See [dog's breakfast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786984/vba-sort-macro-not-working/30787885) and all the trouble the user is having because it wasn't written properly to start and they are reluctant to correct it now beyond bandaids.

Comment: @Jeeped the dog had good breakfast :-). Yes that is right, With-End With is good clue how to use it and so one won't forget to include the expected 'parent' and do not use the implicit one.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is not really evident what this code should achieve, tell you why:
Two worksheets are defined but only one of them is used, also It's not clear to which worksheet the code is to be applied. As it stand now, the code is applied to whatever worksheet is active.

See the code below with adjustments and comments.
The code assumes the procedure should be apply to the Ath worksheet (change as needed)

Although the changes are explained, do let me know of any questions you might have about.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub Mapping()
Rem Worksheet "Map" is only used to obtain lastmap which is never used
Rem Therefore theese line are commented as they do not play any role in the procedure
'Dim Map As Worksheet
'Dim lastmap As Long
'Set Map = Sheets("Mapping")
'lastmap = Map.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row ' NOT USED?

Rem Set array with titles - easy to maintain, and use to command all further intructions avoiding hard codding
Dim aTitles As Variant
aTitles = [{"EDITED","EDITED 2","EDITED 3","EDITED 4"}]

Dim Ath As Worksheet
Dim lastath As Long
Dim Clastath As Integer
Dim X As Integer

    Set Ath = Sheets("Athena Greek God")

    Rem It's not clear to which worksheet the code is to be applied?
    Rem Actually it is applied to whatever worksheet is active
    Rem This code assumes the procedure should be apply to the Ath worksheet
    With Ath '(change as needed)
        lastath = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(1).Resize(, UBound(aTitles)).EntireColumn.Insert     'Using Titles array to insert required number of columns
        With Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastath, UBound(aTitles)))  'Working with the range to be updated
            .Rows(1).Value = aTitles
            .Columns.AutoFit
            .Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)                    'Simplify method to set color

            Clastath = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            Rem Use "Step -1" if you have more than one cell with value = "The Principals Book"
            Rem and you whant to catch the last occurrence. Otherwise no need to use it.
            Rem For X = Clastath To 1 Step -1 '(change if needed as per comment above)
            For X = 1 To Clastath
                If .Cells(1, X).Value = "The Principals Book" Then
                    Rem Old line, left only to show changes (.Value and .Value2)
                    Rem Ath.Range("D2: D" & lastath).Value = Ath.Range(Ath.Cells(2, X), Ath.Cells(lastath, X)).Value2
                    Ath.Range("D2: D" & lastath).Value = Ath.Range(Ath.Cells(2, X), Ath.Cells(lastath, X)).Value2
                    .Columns(4).Value = .Columns(1).Offset(0, X - 1).Value2
                    Exit For    'Exit For...Next after achieving its goal

    End If: Next: End With: End With

    Ath.Activate 'Only used to show\move to the worksheet updated

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code deserves several comments. To begin with, you have to solve your problem (see point 1).
In addition, several points can reduce the chances of error upon modification, and improve efficiency.

1. **Use other methods for copying `Range`s**.
   You have to specify what you want to copy (data, formulas, number formats, etc.) to decide which method to use.

   - Copy only data.

     ```
     Ath.Range("D2:D" & lastath).Value2 = Ath.Range(Ath.Cells(2, x), Ath.Cells(lastath, x)).Value2
     ```

     or

     ```
     Ath.Range(Ath.Cells(2, x), Ath.Cells(lastath, x)).Copy
     Ath.Range("D2:D" & lastath).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     ```
   - Copy (part or all of) number formats. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2).

     ```
     Ath.Range("D2:D" & lastath).Value = Ath.Range(Ath.Cells(2, x), Ath.Cells(lastath, x)).Value
     ```

     or

     ```
     Ath.Range(Ath.Cells(2, x), Ath.Cells(lastath, x)).Copy
     Ath.Range("D2:D" & lastath).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
     ```
   - Copy formulas.

     ```
     Ath.Range(Ath.Cells(2, x), Ath.Cells(lastath, x)).Copy
     Ath.Range("D2:D" & lastath).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas  ' or xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
     ```
   - Copy all.

     ```
     Ath.Range(Ath.Cells(2, x), Ath.Cells(lastath, x)).Copy
     Ath.Range("D2:D" & lastath).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
     ```

     or

     ```
     Ath.Range(Ath.Cells(2, x), Ath.Cells(lastath, x)).Copy Destination:=Ath.Range("D2:D" & lastath)
     ```
2. **Fully qualify your `Range`s**.
   This issue shows up once and again (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20605401/2707864)).
   *What does this mean?* Do not use `Cells`, `Range`, `Rows` or `Columns` without specifying which `Worksheet` they belong to, unless you specifically want to do that (and even in that case, explicitly using `ActiveSheet` improves readability and reduces the chances of errors, similar to using `Option Explicit`).
   For instance,

   ```
   lastath = Ath.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   ```

   will take `Rows.Count` from the `ActiveSheet`, which might not be `Ath`. You likely do not want that.
   The correct form is

   ```
   lastath = Ath.Cells(Ath.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   ```

   Fix all other code.
   *Note*: in this case, code continues execution and the mistake may go unnoticed, as it produces a valid result. In other cases, code without fully qualified `Range`s will throw an error (e.g., with something like `sheet1.Range(Cells(...`, when `sheet1` is not the `ActiveSheet`).
3. **Your code seems inefficient**.
   You might be copying data many times into the same `Range`. It is better to find the leftmost cell in row 1, containing `"The Principals Book"`, and copy the range for that column into `Range("D2:D" & lastath)`. Use

   ```
   Dim x As Long
   For x = 1 To Clastath
       If Ath.Cells(1, x) = "The Principals Book" Then
           Ath.Range("D2:D" & lastath).Value2 = Ath.Range(Ath.Cells(2, x), Ath.Cells(lastath, x)).Value2   ' or alternatives above
           Exit For
       End If
   Next
   ```
4. **It is not clear in which `Worksheet` you want columns inserted**.
   It seems to be `Ath`. The other `Worksheet` is not used.
5. **You can insert many columns at once. You can also enter data into a range at once**.

   ```
   Ath.Columns("A:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
   Ath.Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("EDITED", "EDITED 2", "EDITED 3", "EDITED 4")
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1.Remove the space in your string  address: 
Before:

```
ath.Range("D2: D" & lastath))
```

After:

```
ath.Range("D2:D" & lastath))
```

2a. If you only want to copy the values, then use .value at the end of your range references:
Before:

```
ath.Range("D2:D" & lastath).value = ath.Range(ath.Cells(2, x), ath.Cells(lastath, x))
```

After:

```
ath.Range("D2:D" & lastath).value = ath.Range(ath.Cells(2, x).value, ath.Cells(lastath, x).value).value
```

2b. If you want values and formats then use .copy (destination):
Before:

```
ath.Range("D2:D" & lastath).value = ath.Range(ath.Cells(2, x), ath.Cells(lastath, x))
```

After:

```
ath.Range("D2:D" & lastath).copy(ath.Range(ath.Cells(2, x).value, ath.Cells(lastath, x).value))
```

Also, you should always reference the worksheet of a references range (e.g. `ws.range("A1").value`). You might also consider using a worksheet's .codename rather then .name if this isn't just a quick an dirty project.