# Code not looping through sheets

Tags: vba, excel, loops

The following code is deleting too much on first sheet and then not looping to second sheet?? Error appearing on .FindNext statement.

```
Sub FindAndExecute3()
Dim Loc As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With sh.UsedRange
        Set Loc = .Cells.Find(What:="AUTO.WHSE.")
        If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
          Do Until Loc Is Nothing
            Rows(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & (ActiveCell.Row + 2)).Delete
            Set Loc = .FindNext(Loc)
          Loop
        End If
    End With
    Set Loc = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: how can we know what is not correct if you don't tell what you would like to achieve with your code? And can you provide the text of the error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to **fully qualify your `Range`s**. 
This issue shows up once and again (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20605401/2707864)).

*What does this mean?* Do not use `Cells`, `Range`, `Rows` or `Columns` without specifying which `Worksheet` they belong to, unless you specifically want to do that (and even in that case, explicitly using `ActiveSheet` improves readability and reduces the chances of errors, similar to using `Option Explicit`).
For instance, replace

```
Rows(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & (ActiveCell.Row + 2)).Delete
```

with

```
sh.Rows(sh.<something>.Row & ":" & (sh.<something>.Row + 2)).Delete
```

I am assuming the `Range` to be deleted spans `Row` numbers taken from something related to `sh`.

*Note 1*: In this case, even without qualifying `Range`s, code continues execution and the mistake may go unnoticed, as it produces a valid result. In other cases, code without fully qualified `Range`s will throw an error (e.g., with something like `sheet1.Range(Cells(...`, when `sheet1` is not the `ActiveSheet`).**

*Note 2*: You can work with the `ActiveCell` only when the `Worksheet` that it is on is the `ActiveSheet` [[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221612%28v=office.11%29.aspx)].

Comment: You also need to record the first found address and check when you've returned to it, otherwise the Do...Loop will continue.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Comment: Thank you all for your questions and efforts. I have updated the code a little bit. It is looping through the sheets, but when there are 2 instance of AUTO.WHSE., it only acts on the first one.

Comment: Not sure how to enter this code, sorry, new to stack.    [code]Sub deleteRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        Cells.Find(What:="AUTO.WHSE.", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
            
        Rows(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & (ActiveCell.Row + 2)).Delete
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub[/code]

Comment: It looks like you are carrying out only one `Find`. And check my Note 2.