# In one program this code works and in similar program this shows run time error 1004 in copying cell cell.value

Tags: excel, vba

In one program this code works and in similar program this shows run time error 1004 in copying cell cell.value.

The error is column number is not assigning

```
Dim Next_6, PriceChange, Price_i, MyWorksheetLastRow As Long
MyWorksheetLastRow = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Next_6 = ColInstance("Next_6_months", 1)
'Next_6 = 15
For Price_i = 2 To MyWorksheetLastRow
Cells(Price_i, Next_6).Value = Cells(Price_i, Next_6).Value & " " & Cells(Price_i, Next_6 + 1).Value
Next Price_i

Function ColInstance(HeadingString As String, InstanceNum As Long)
Dim ColNum As Long
On Error Resume Next
ColNum = 0
For X = 1 To InstanceNum
ColNum = (Range("A1").Offset(0, ColNum).Column) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(HeadingString, Range("A1").Offset(0, ColNum + 1).Resize(1, Columns.Count - (ColNum + 1)), 0)
Next
ColInstance = ColNum
End Function
```

While debugging, value 15 (column number which matches "Next_6_months" is not assigning to Next_6)

Why So?

Comment: Your `for x` loop goes from `1 to 1` but never uses the `x`?

Comment: but is it a problem? its a general function. I want to find the first instance only. So I gave one.

Comment: `ColNum = (Range("A1").Offset(0, 0).Column) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(HeadingString, Range("A1").Offset(0, 0+ 1).Resize(1, Columns.Count - (0+ 1)), 0)` using `colnum` instead of `x` - what is your function supposed to do? You don't need the X or the colnum variables

Comment: What does "While debugging, value 15 (column number which matches "Next_6_months" is not assigning to Next_6)" mean? Check: 1) the value of `MyWorksheetLastRow`, 2) which value of `Price_i` leads to error, 3) which is the `ActiveSheet`, 4) if you can `Debug.Print` `Cells(Price_i, Next_6).Value & " " & Cells(Price_i, Next_6 + 1).Value` in the immediate window, just prior to getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear, so I will guess.

Your code has several points to fix:

1. You have to **fully qualify your `Range`s**. 
   This issue shows up once and again (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20605401/2707864)).

   *What does this mean?* Do not use `Cells`, `Range`, `Rows` or `Columns` without specifying which `Worksheet` they belong to, unless you specifically want to do that (and even in that case, explicitly using `ActiveSheet` improves readability and reduces the chances of errors, similar to using `Option Explicit`).
   For instance, you use

   ```
   MyWorksheetLastRow = Worksheets(1)...
   ```

   at one point, and in many other cases you use nothing, which defaults to `ActiveSheet`. Check if this is intended.
2. Fix declaration of variables and function.
   At the beginning of the module, use

   ```
   Option Explicit
   ```

   and then fix this

   ```
   Dim Next_6 As Long, PriceChange As ..., Price_i As Long, MyWorksheetLastRow As Long
   ```

   and

   ```
   Function ColInstance(HeadingString As String, InstanceNum As Long) As Long
   Dim ColNum As Long, X As Long
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned previously there are some typo's in your code declaring variables, but it is also likely your ColInstance function doesn't always return what you expect

The following rewrite should be of benefit...

#### Update

Altered slightly to allow the rows to point directly to sheet1

```
Sub AssignValues()
    Dim Next_6 As Long, PriceChange As Long, Price_i As Long, MyWorksheetLastRow As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        MyWorksheetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Next_6 = ColInstance("Next_6_months", 1)
        If Next_6 > 0 Then
            For Price_i = 2 To MyWorksheetLastRow
                .Cells(Price_i, Next_6).Value = .Cells(Price_i, Next_6).Value & " " & .Cells(Price_i, Next_6 + 1).Value
            Next Price_i
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Function ColInstance(Header As String, Optional Instance As Long = 1) As Long
    ' Function returns 0 if Header doesn't exist in specified row
    ' Function returns -1 if Header exists but number of instances < specified
    ColInstance = 0
    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    Dim c As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Rows(1)
        Set c = .Find(Header, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            FirstAdr = c.Address
            Do
                i = i + 1
                If i > Instance Then
                    ColInstance = c.Column
                    Exit Do
                End If
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While c.Address <> FirstAdr
            If c.Address = FirstAdr And Instance > 1 Then ColInstance = -1
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But its not working. "c" value in function remains "Nothing" even though "Next_6_months" is there in first row of workbook. Even though workbook is opened and all, function is not finding the exact word. I tried different strings in first row, still function is not finding them. Is there any error in "With Rows(1)
        Set c = .Find(Header, LookIn:=xlValues)" ?

Comment: The function will find the header if it is row 1 of the spreadsheet (Sheet1)
If it is in row 2 or 3 etc, then the code will need to be updated to reflect that.
The code has also been slightly updated to more explicitly point to the worksheet in use. Again with multiple sheets open, this may need to be updated to point to which sheet you require.