# Error with Nested loops in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, for-loop, compiler-errors, nested, vba

I am having problems with my code on Excel VBA. I am trying to write a nested loop. But I keep getting the compile error: Next without For ( the line with Next r)

Here's my code

```
Sub clear()
r = 2
i = 310

For c = 15 To 28

r = 2
i = 310

For r = 2 To 306

If Cells(r, c) > Cells(306, c) Then
If Cells(r, 4) <> Cells(i - 1, c) Then
[ Cells(i, c) = Cells(r, 4) i = i + 1]


r = r + 1
Next r

Cells(308, c) = i - 309

Next c

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: try indenting your code, you might find that you have 2 x `If`s without `End If`, that might be the reason. Also, in the code you shared, you are not doing anything with the variable `I`, you can replace `I` with 310 (or declare it at the top as `Const`)

Comment: Thanks @ShaiRado,  i added the End if  and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are (at least) missing `endif`s.
Please check if code posted below follows your intended task.

Plus:

1. It is always convenient to [require explicit declaration of variables](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html).
2. It is always convenient to not use `Cells` alone, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20605401/2707864).
3. Line `r = r + 1` is strange. `r` is already incremented by looping.

Suggested amended code (I do not have a system at hand to test it).

```
Option Explicit

Sub clear()
    Dim r as Integer, i as Integer, c as Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet   ' or whatever you want
    'r = 2
    i = 310
    For c = 15 To 28
        'r = 2
        'i = 310
        For r = 2 To 306
            If ( ws.Cells(r, c) > ws.Cells(306, c) ) Then
                If ( ws.Cells(r, 4) <> ws.Cells(i - 1, c) ) Then
                    [ ws.Cells(i, c) = ws.Cells(r, 4) i = i + 1]   ' check syntax
                endif
            endif
            r = r + 1    ' check this
        Next r
        ws.Cells(308, c) = i - 309
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: you have a `For r = 2 To 306` loop , and before letting it increment `Next r` you are keeping another `r = r + 1` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado - Absolutely, I was commenting on that strange line. Even though in very rare cases one might want to do that, I do not think this is one such case.

Comment: @sancho.s how to change the focus to a different sheet. I wrote a code and i want to run it for sheet 3, but the code is running for sheet 2.

Comment: @FranklinVarghese - `set ws = Worksheets("sheet 3")` or similar.